# Detect click on fabric.Rect canvas object

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

In FabricJS there are many events to detect if object is scaled, moved, rotated or selected. but `object:selected` doesn't register the last object clicked .

When I create an object, for example a rectangle:

```
    var id2 = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 50,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: '#dedede',
        opacity: 0.5,
        id: id2
    });

    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.sendToBack(rect);
```

then assign an ID to the object.

to detect if the object is clicked I use

```
canvas.on('object:selected', showCoord);
```

but `object:selected` doesn't register the last object clicked.

Doest there exist a click or dbclick event to attach to fabric shape?

Answer (score 3):

You can use events like `mousedown, mousedblclick` on objects, and `mouse:down, mouse:dblclick` on canvas.

***DEMO***

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: "#FF0000",
  stroke: "#000",
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
});
canvas.add(rect);
rect.on('mousedblclick', ()=>{
  console.log('on dblClick rect');
});
rect.on('mousedown', ()=>{
  console.log('on mousedown rect');
});
canvas.on('mouse:down', (options)=>{
  console.log('on canvas mousedown', options.target ? options.target.type : '');
});
canvas.on('mouse:dblclick', (options)=>{
  console.log('on canvas mouse dblclick', options.target ? options.target.type : '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to just handle the selection at object level rather than trying to filter all events on the canvas

```
   let newRect = new fabric.Rect(<Your object props>);
    
   newRect.on("selected", (element) => {
      // do stuff here
     console.log("selected", element);
   });
```

Comment: If the object `selectable: false` then you won't get the `selected` event fired.